# Determine the error

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging a program that crashes 10 times in different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531742/debugging-a-program-that-crashes-10-times-in-different-places)

You are given a the source to a application which is crashing when
run. After running it 10 times in a debugger, you find it never
crashes in the same place. The application is single threaded, and
uses only the C standard library. What programming errors could be
causing this crash? How would you test each one?

Comment: Wow, that's actually a copy-and-paste duplicate. Haven't seen that before.

Comment: Well, I have this question. If @ravi would have commented on the original question, **Possibly no one would have followed up, since that question might be old and burried. What does one do in that situation ?** I faced it many times, then there is need to start new post with similar question. But yes, exact copy-paste is not the way.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer error. You're trying to read/write an undefined pointer - do a find and replace for free(x) -> free(x);x=NULL.

Edit: Should also check for assignment; are you doing anything like this?

```
int *a;
a++;
```